# Android set locale not work on OPPO mobile?

Tags: android

I need to build an app that user can change the language. This is my code:

```
public class LocalizedBaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context context) {
        String language = "vi";
        Context localizedContext = getLocalizedContext(context, language);
        super.attachBaseContext(localizedContext);
    }

    public static Context getLocalizedContext(Context context, String language) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            return updateResources(context, language);
        }

        return updateResourcesLegacy(context, language);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private static Context updateResources(Context context, String language) {

        Locale locale = new Locale(language);

        Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();

        LocaleList localeList = new LocaleList(locale);
        localeList.setDefault(localeList);
        configuration.setLocales(localeList);

        return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static Context updateResourcesLegacy(Context context, String language) {

        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Resources resources = context.getResources();

        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        configuration.locale = locale;

        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

        return context;
    }
}
```

All other activities will extend from this activity instead of directly from `AppCompatActivity`.

It worked well on my Xiaomi phone, but not on an Oppo phone.
Does anyone have the experience to implement multi-language app? I need some suggestions to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer. That is using:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("vi", "VN");
```

Instead of:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("vi");
```